# Fisheye effect on IOS

Tags: objective-c, ios

I'd like to create a Fisheye effect shown in many IOS Apps and some other interesting effects like color burn and so on ...
Which is the best way to work on these features ? Could you suggest me some useful links or code ?

I need understand in which direction i have to go to work on graphic effects that take an image as input and obtain a modified result of that as output. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Which is the best way to work on these
>   features ?

It depends of how far you decide to go. Some simple effects you can make with Quartz (native iOS/MacOSX graphic subsystem). For 2d game developement, use cocos2d-iphone. It has lens effect and burning flame and many other interesting effects. [Some demos.](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/about)

For advanced graphical effects, learn OpenGL ES. [Official site](http://www.khronos.org/opengles/)

Comment: But in your opinion i can create effect like "fisheye" using Quartz ?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't really know:  i used to work with OpenGL ES an Cocos2d-iphone (which is based on OpenGL ES 1.1), but not with Quartz. According to "Quartz 2D graphics for Mac OS X developers" fisheye effect can be done with Quartz.

Comment: I read about that on developer guide, but the problem is that these effects are only for OSX not for IOS :(

Comment: So, it seems OpenGL ES is the only option.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/459108/quartz-2d-opengles-geometric-distortions-on-images-preferrably-using-cgimage

Answer (score 1):

try: 
http://wiki.panotools.org/Fisheye_Projection
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisheye_lens
http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/fisheye/index.php